# Iterating in for-each loop Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, foreach

I have an ArrayList,where I search for needed element and then add the needed part of it to another ArrayList. The problem is that if I want to keep searching for the words,not only one word,I don't know how to keep going on the elements through the loop. With the using of iterator, I wouldn't be able to search for things I need.

```
public static  ArrayList<String> FindWord(){
ArrayList<String> rewrite=new ArrayList<>();//
    ArrayList<String> word=Reading();// rewrites the data from one string to other
    String userinput=Chat();
  for(String elmt:word){
        if (elmt.contains(userinput) && elmt.contains("=")) {
                String[] parts=elmt.split("\\=");
                rewrite.add(parts[1]);
             // here I must do something like word.next
  }

    }
   System.out.println(rewrite);
    return rewrite;  // RETURNS THE SYNONIM OF THE WORD
}
```

So,it goes like if I input "hello", it will find me the word "greeting",which is a synonim in my text file. If I input "awesome", it will find the word "thanks", but if I input both of them it will input an empty array, like nothing is found instead of " greeting, thanks"

UPD:
The Reading() returns:

```
public static ArrayList<String> Reading() {
    Scanner inputreader = null;
    try {
        inputreader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("D:\\sinonims.txt"));
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {                // OPENS FILE WITH SINONIMS
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    ArrayList<String> Sins=new ArrayList();
   while(inputreader.hasNextLine()){
      String l=inputreader.nextLine();
       Sins.add(l);   // REWRITES DATA FROM FILE TO ARRATLIST
   }
    inputreader.close();
    System.out.print(Sins);
    return Sins;
}
```

`public static String Chat(){
        System.out.println("Let's start talking.");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String line=in.nextLine();
        return line;
    }`

Comment: Please show what `Reading()` is returning and what you want `rewrite` to contain

Comment: with your statements // here I must do something like word.next, you don#t next to do next, because the for loop goes through all the elements in the word

Comment: can you provide more details to the data you are reading and what Chat() and Reading() is returning.

Comment: @cricket_007 done

Comment: As text, please, not an image

Comment: @cricket_007  now better.
A file consists of synonims like
hello=hii
what's up =hii
and so on.

Comment: Each call to the `FindWord()` method is only accepting one user input, not multiple inputs. Is that what you are trying to ask? Because the `for(String elmt:word)` is already iterating over all the elements. Print them out, you'll see them

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for a help.Now I see that everything's OK in Reading().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to accept many inputs, you'll need to loop around the input & for loop.

The for loop already loops over all the words.

Note: I replaced `contains` for `startsWith` to prevent you catching the word on the other side of the equals

```
static ArrayList<String> word=Reading();

public static  ArrayList<String> FindWord(){
    ArrayList<String> rewrite=new ArrayList<>();
    String userinput = "" ;
    while (true) {
        userinput=Chat();
        if (userinput.equals("quit")) break;
        for(String elmt:word){
            if (elmt.startsWith(userinput) && elmt.contains("=")) {
                String[] parts=elmt.split("\\=");
                rewrite.add(parts[1]);
            }
    }
   System.out.println(rewrite);
   return rewrite;  // RETURNS THE SYNONIM OF THE WORD
}
```

I can't really say this is the best way to approach your problem because it seems you need a Hashmap, not an Arraylist

Comment: Yep, I was also goint to post with edit that HashMap is better approach to do this.

Comment: @cricket_007 Is there something to prevent double search? I mean while looking for word "good" it findes it both as a a synonim of a "great" and as a synonim of "good morning?And vica versa.

Answer (score 1):

You should split the input string `userinput` with some specific delimiter.

Then for each word, Iterate through the splitted array and give each word as `input` , Find its Synonym with your technique and add it to the `arraylist`.

This can be implemented by doing some changes in your code.

```
public static  ArrayList<String> FindWord()
{
    ArrayList<String> rewrite=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> word=Reading();
    String userinput=Chat();
    String inputs[]=userinput.split(","); //Considering delimiter is comma(",") in user input

    for(String input : inputs) //Giving each word as input at a time and search for it in word String
    {
        for(String elmt:word)
        {
            if (elmt.contains(input) && elmt.contains("=")) 
            {
                    String[] parts=elmt.split("\\=");
                    rewrite.add(parts[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(rewrite);
    return rewrite;  // RETURNS THE SYNONIM OF THE WORD
}
```

So Here I am considering that the input is with delimiter `Comma(",")` so I have splitted input string with `Comma(",")` as you have given description in comments about your problem with space as delimiter.

When you will print the ArrayList, Automatically Output will be printed in separated manner with `comma(, )`.

So for Input : `hello,awesome` It will give output as `greeting, thanks`.

Comment: Is there something to prevent double search? I mean while looking for word "good" it findes it both as a a synonim of a "great" and as a synonim of "good morning?And vica versa.

Comment: I didn't get your question. Try to rephrase it with better example.@VladDemyan

Comment: So,the whole word can be a part of another phrase.Such as word "What" is a synonym of "question" in ,my file,but at the same time it is a part of a phrase "What  is up", that is actually a "greeting" in the same file. And when I input the phrase, it will be found both as a question and greeting. So it looks like the String inputs works correctly not every time @Sanket Makani

Comment: Then take input as `What,What is up`(Comma Separated) and Change delimiters to `","` from `" "`. I am editing my answer check it.@VladDemyan

Answer (score 1):

contains fetches you exact match, split the text and match accordingly, store the results in new array list

Answer (score 1):

you can create another arraylist and add your **userinput** values one by one into that list . you can iterate this **newly created arraylist** by using new **for each loop** on top of the current for each loop.